# Group by a Collection of String with Stream groupingby in java8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

How to use the expression `Stream` [`groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) operation of Java 8 to finish this?

I want to turn a `Set<String> allTextFileList` containing:

```
20150101_00b667339f32fcff37db6e89aea53065.txt
20150101_06d0e76e4782cff3ce455feecf72b80d.txt
20150301_11f706c03860068e7e736ff943525504.txt
20150301_33719f3b98081b32e9ffd3b932e1902d.txt
```

to a `Map<String, Set<String>> textFileListBydate` containing

```
20150101 ->
 - 20150101_00b667339f32fcff37db6e89aea53065.txt
 - 20150101_06d0e76e4782cff3ce455feecf72b80d.txt

20150301 ->
 - 20150301_11f706c03860068e7e736ff943525504.txt
 - 20150301_33719f3b98081b32e9ffd3b932e1902d.txt
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, you want to group by the first part of the filename, i.e. the substring starting from the beginning to the first index of `"_"`.

For this task, you can use [`Collectors.groupingBy(classifier, downstream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-).

- `classifier` is a function determines how to classify object in the resulting `Map`. In this case, it is the function that will return the first part of the filename.
- `downstream` is a `Collector` that reduces all the values having the same classifier. In this case, we need to use a collector that collects to a `Set`, i.e. [`Collectors.toSet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toSet--).

Code:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> textFileListBydate = 
            allTextFileList.stream()
                           .collect(groupingBy(s -> s.substring(0, s.indexOf('_')), toSet()));
```